# Como alterar atributo de elemento pai de dentro do filho

Tags: javascript, react

Quero que ao clicar no meu `Icon` ele mude propriedades do primeiro elemento. Onde estou errando? Como fazer?

```js
import React from 'react';
import './header.css';
import { Col, Container, Row, MediaBox, Icon } from "react-materialize";


class Header extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { active: true };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }
    handleClick() {
        this.setState(state => ({
            active: !state.active
        }));
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Col 
                s={12} 
                m={4} 
                l={2} 
                className="pink darken-1 text-white header" 
                thisActive={this.state.active ? 'active' : ''}>
                <Container>
                    <Row>
                        <Col s={6} m={4} l={2} className="header-logo">
                            <MediaBox className="header-logo-img">
                                <img src={require("./img/logo-insta-header.png")} />
                            </MediaBox>
                        </Col>
                        <Col s={6} m={4} l={2} className="header-menu">
                            <Icon medium right className="header-menu-btn text-white" onClick={this.handleClick}>
                                menu
                            </Icon>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Container>
            </Col>
        );
    }
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: E que seria o "primeiro elemento" a div `header-menu`?? Vc acha que um código em JS puro poderia te ajudar ou tem que ser em React mesmo?

Comment: O primeiro elemento seria o .header e um código js puro poderia ajudar sim.

Comment: Ok Rafael deixei uma resposta, tentei seguir ao máximo a estrutura que vc tem, na verdade acho que ficou bem parecido e vai ser fácil de vc adaptar o JS pro React ;)

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que eu entendi você quer alterar um elemento do pai por dentro do filho ? Se sim vamos lá !

**Elemento que eu quero alterar**

```
<h1>{this.sate.texto}</h1>
```

**No pai você definiria a função que alteraria o estado `texto: " ",` e depois a mandaria para o filho.**

```
<SeuComponente NomedaFunc={ this.NomeDaFunc.bind(this) } />
```

**E de dentro do filho você chamaria ela**

```
this.props.NomeDaFunc(Parametro1)
```

Espero ter ajudado

Answer (score 1):

Conforme convesado no comentário fiz esse modelo com JS puro e seguindo a sua estrutura de HTML, inclusive com o Bootstrap que me parece que vc tb está usando ele.

Veja que quando eu clico no menu eu adiciono uma classe "`ativo`" no elemento que tb tem a classe `.header`, ai não importa muito a estrutura de tab, pois eu vou selecionar o elemento pela classe e não pela ordem ou index das tags.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da imagem acima.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" />
<style>
    .header.ativo {
        background-color: green;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    
<div class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="header-logo col-6">
                <div class="header-logo-img">
                    <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="header-menu col-6">
                <i medium right class="header-menu-btn text-danger" onclick="ativa()">
                    menu
                </i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    function ativa() {
        var pai = document.querySelector('.header');

        pai.classList.toggle('ativo')
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @fullstack-overkill sua resposta está no comentária na pergunta http://prntscr.com/ofy2ij eu perguntei antes de responder, e para ele faz sentido []´s